Error con diccionarios y formatos json
Dado este código
@post("/habitacion")
def nuevaHabitacion():
    try:
        datos = request.json    # obtenemos el json
    except:
        raise ValueError

    # información básica de la nueva habitación
    habitacionNueva = {
        "identificador": str(len(hotel)),
        "plazas": datos["plazas"],  # lo obtenemos del json
        "equipamiento": datos["equipamiento"],  # lo obtenemos del json
        "ocupada": False
    }

    hotel.append(habitacionNueva)   # la añadimos al hotel (conjunto de habitaciones)

    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'   # indicamos al cliente que lo que le devolvemos es un json

    return json.dumps(habitacionNueva)

Tengo problemas con el diccionario habitacionNueva, concretamente en "plazas": datos["plazas"] y claro, otra forma de hacerlo no sé hacerlo, en concreto, el error es el siguiente:
"plazas": datos["plazas"],  # lo obtenemos del json
          ~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

Gracias por la ayuda.

Estaría bien un poco de contexto, como la librería que estás usando

Pese a que no se que librería estás usando, el error te dice que la variable datos es un string, no un diccionario, así que si con print(datos) te muestra correctamente el diccionario, te bastará con parsearlo, por ejemplo haciendo:
import json

@post("/habitacion")
def nuevaHabitacion():
    try:
        datos = json.loads(request.json)
    except:
        raise ValueError()
    ...


Efectivamente, con eso ya no saltan los errores, estaba usando la librería Bottle, pero no entiendo entonces que hace exactamente request.json
Como se parsearía usando datos = request.json ??

@PabloRivero según pone en la documentación https://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/api.html?highlight=json#bottle.BaseRequest.json debería parseartelo, pero no se porque no lo está haciendo

@RodrigoLlanes También dice que el atributo json tiene el json parseado si content-type es "application/json". Así que es posible que content-type no cumpla con ese requisito y así "reaccione" la librería ante esto.

@DanteS. ya, pero si miras el código fuente https://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/_modules/bottle.html#BaseRequest.json si el content-type está mal devuelve None no el texto plano, pero supongo que puede ser que el tenga otra versión
